# In Swift, is it faster to calculate the sum of 2 values twice or calculate once and store the result in a variable?

Tags: swift

I am creating a performance heavy application and was wondering which way of writing the same code runs faster in runtime.

Option 1:

```
let a = 1 + 2
self.doSomething(with: a)
self.doSomethingElse(with: a)
```

Option 2:

```
self.doSomething(with: 1 + 2)
self.doSomethingElse(with: 1 + 2)
```

If any of the options is faster, is this also true for structs? e.g.

```
let a = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
self.doSomething(with: a)
self.doSomethingElse(with: a)
```

or

```
self.doSomething(with: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
self.doSomethingElse(with: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
```

Edit: added real world scenario

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
      return
    }

    let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
    let lastPoint = touch.previousLocation(in: view)


    //////////

    let newPoint1 = CGPoint(x: lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y)
    let newPoint2 = CGPoint(x: lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y, y: lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x)

    // OR

    let newX = lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x
    let newY = lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y
    let newPoint11 = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
    let newPoint22 = CGPoint(x: newY, y: newX)

    ///////

    print([newPoint1, newPoint2])
    print([newPoint11, newPoint22])
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `let` to compute the value once.  This tells the Swift compiler that the same value is being used twice and allows the Swift compiler/optimizer to generate tighter code.  If you know that the value is the same, share that information with the compiler and don't make the optimizer figure that out itself (because it might not be able to).

In your example with `1 + 2`, that most assuredly generates the same code in both instances because of [*Constant Folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). The compiler will do the `1 + 2` at compile time, and the generated code will just pass `3` to each function call.

In your second example, the Swift compiler might not be able to recognize that you've generated two versions of the same `struct`, and it could emit code that generates the `struct` twice.  By assigning that struct to a constant `a`, Swift then knows it can pass the same `struct` to the two functions and avoid creating it twice.

**General rule:** Giving the compiler more information allows it to make better optimizations.

**Added benefit:** Using `let` makes your code more readable and easier to modify.

---

In your **real world scenario**:

```
let newPoint1 = CGPoint(x: lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y)
let newPoint2 = CGPoint(x: lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y, y: lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x)

// OR

let newX = lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x
let newY = lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y
let newPoint11 = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
let newPoint22 = CGPoint(x: newY, y: newX)
```

Again the compiler will likely generate the same code because of a technique called [*Common Subexpression Elimination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) where the compiler detects and eliminates redundant expressions.  But why rely on this?  You know the values represent `newX` and `newY`, so by computing those first as constants you 1) Let the compiler know to compute this expression once, 2) Document to yourself and your readers the intent of the code.

The second example is clearer and easier to modify in addition to giving extra hints to the compiler/optimizer.  Overall, it is better code.

Comment: Thanks! 
What if I do not use constants? please see the edit of the post

Comment: See "common subexpression elimination" for the common optimizer technique that applies here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination

Answer (score 5):

These are literally the same. The compiler will inline `a` for you. How do we know? We ask the compiler.

## [first.swift](https://godbolt.org/z/_bwcer)

```
struct X {
    func doSomething(with value: Int) {
        print("something: \(value)")
    }

    func doSomethingElse(with value: Int) {
        print("somethingElse: \(value)")
    }


    func f() {
        let a = 1 + 2
        doSomething(with: a)
        doSomethingElse(with: a)
    }
}

X().f()


$ swiftc -O -emit-sil first.c

// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  %2 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int64, 3          // user: %3
  %3 = struct $Int (%2 : $Builtin.Int64)          // users: %8, %6, %4
  debug_value %3 : $Int, let, name "a"            // id: %4
  // function_ref specialized X.doSomething(with:)
  %5 = function_ref @$s5first1XV11doSomething4withySi_tFTf4nd_n : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> () // user: %6
  %6 = apply %5(%3) : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> ()
  // function_ref specialized X.doSomethingElse(with:)
  %7 = function_ref @$s5first1XV15doSomethingElse4withySi_tFTf4nd_n : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> () // user: %8
  %8 = apply %7(%3) : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> ()
  %9 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0          // user: %10
  %10 = struct $Int32 (%9 : $Builtin.Int32)       // user: %11
  return %10 : $Int32                             // id: %11
} // end sil function 'main'
```

## [second.swift](https://godbolt.org/z/SwG1Ua)

```
...
    func f() {
        doSomething(with: 1 + 2)
        doSomethingElse(with: 1 + 2)
    }
...

$ swiftc -O -emit-sil second.swift

// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  %2 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int64, 3          // user: %3
  %3 = struct $Int (%2 : $Builtin.Int64)          // users: %7, %5
  // function_ref specialized X.doSomething(with:)
  %4 = function_ref @$s6second1XV11doSomething4withySi_tFTf4nd_n : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> () // user: %5
  %5 = apply %4(%3) : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> ()
  // function_ref specialized X.doSomethingElse(with:)
  %6 = function_ref @$s6second1XV15doSomethingElse4withySi_tFTf4nd_n : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> () // user: %7
  %7 = apply %6(%3) : $@convention(thin) (Int) -> ()
  %8 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0          // user: %9
  %9 = struct $Int32 (%8 : $Builtin.Int32)        // user: %10
  return %9 : $Int32                              // id: %10
} // end sil function 'main'
```

Notice in both cases `f()` vanishes. This is just `main()` because `f()` gets inlined anyway. Then notice that in both cases, we have these lines:

```
%2 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int64, 3          // user: %3
%3 = struct $Int (%2 : $Builtin.Int64)          // users: %8, %6, %4
```

The complier sees that there's a computation of the literal value 3, and it computes that at compile time and sticks it in a *compiler* variable (%3). The only difference is that in the first case, the compiler emits a `debug_value` so that the debugger has a local name for %3. That's going to be completely irrelevant later if debugging information is removed. But other than that, it's literally the same code. There is no memory or registered allocated to hold the 3. It's known at compile time, and injected wherever it's referenced.

Do whichever is clearer in your code. The compiler will take care of it.

To your question of CGPoint, you can do the same thing. You'll see that the optimizer can detect that these are constants, too. At the SIL level it'll generate two CGFloats, and put them together into a CGPoint (and it'll reuse that with or without the local variable). But if you look at the final assembly output, it'll generally be able to simplify the entire struct down to its final byte-by-byte representation (and often inline that directly into the `print` call). For example, I created a `CGPoint(x: 999, y: 888)`. The emitted assembly for `doSomething` is:

```
    movabsq $7956005065853857651, %rsi
    movabsq $-1215907691987450521, %rdx
    callq   _$sSS5write2toyxz_ts16TextOutputStreamRzlF
```

Since I only call `doSomething` one time, the compiler realized that it could just hard-code the exact values needed for the string interpolation directly into the assembly out (you'll find these same two "random" numbers in `doSomethingElse` as well). It's not quite smart enough to do the string interpolation in the compile step, but it knows all the literals involved.

Write clearly. Let the optimizer do its job. Then, and only then, explore whether you can do better. Never second-guess the optimizer without careful testing. It's usually (though not always) smarter than you.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer, very helpful. 
Is this also true for the cases when im not working with constants?
For example here
https://imgur.com/a/8Q87lHf

Comment: Generally, yes, but again the guidance holds: don't guess. Write clearly, then check what the optimizer actually does. Check directly using `-O -emit-sil` (and even `-O -emit-assembly`) and test with proper performance benchmarks (remembering that these are difficult to do in general; it's best when possible to just test against your actual code rather than trying to do any kind of artificial benchmark).

Comment: For your edited "real-world" example, I would absolutely not guess at all. I'd just run it in Instruments and see where any bottlenecks actually occur. But never write something awkward "for performance" that you haven't proven is actually faster in this specific case. Write clearly. If you can come up with some trivial transformation that would make this faster in an important way, then the compiler almost certainly does that automatically. You usually are going to get your performance boosts by finding work that doesn't need to be done at all, and avoiding that, rather than tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it’s always faster to do less “work.” In option 2, you’re doing `1+2` twice, so it will take “longer.” I say “longer” because it depends on what you’re doing with whether or not you’ll see any difference. As for using a variable `let a = 1 + 2`, there’s a tradeoff between space and time. Option 1 takes less time but more space, while option 2 takes more time but less space.

This isn’t necessarily Swift specific.

Comment: I guess what confuses me is that it got to take some time to assign a variable and i do not know if assigning the variable is faster then calculating a sum of two values.

Comment: @t0a0 In general, the time it takes to assign the variable is mostly the actual calculation of the variable’s value. Assigning it does take a little bit of time, but with most modern programming languages, like Swift, it’s pretty negligent.

Comment: @t0a0 If you really want to check for yourself, you can just time it: https://gist.github.com/boxed/ff6849a1e50e1c8c3bca31383cfd4fb3

Comment: thanks. I actually tried it, and it seems like Option 2 is much better  
https://imgur.com/a/rjJBP1b

Comment: Timing things in playgrounds is completely meaningless. Not only is it unoptimized, the requirement to display things in the right-hand gutter wildly throws off any performance measurement. Your time is always going to be dominated by the time required to create the strings for display.

Comment: In most modern compiled languages, it's not just negligible, it's exactly zero. If there's a trivial and highly mechanical "rearrange it this way and it'll be faster" then the optimizer almost certainly already does that for you.